# psql transaction block vs anonymous code block

Tags: postgresql, transactions, ddl

what is the best way to rename a column if exists inside a `pl/sql` script using `psql.exe` and without rolling back the whole script:

transaction block (begin/commit)

```
begin;
    alter table table1 rename column c2 to c3;
commit;
```

or anonymous code block with exception handling (do/begin/exception/end)

```
do
$$
    begin
        alter table table1 rename column c2 to c3;
    exception
        when undefined_column then raise notice 'column c2 does not exist';
    end;
$$;
```

Comment: Running the `begin/commit` in `psql` will get you something like: `BEGIN ERROR:  column "c2" does not exist ROLLBACK` and then will continue on. So you are not really gaining anything with the `DO` function. Comes down to personal preference.

Comment: One benefit with `DO` would be to capture the exception and log it to a table.